# Detect end dragging/zooming MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit, mkmapviewdelegate

Is there a way to determine if a `MKMapView` drag and zoom stops?

Right now I've added an `UIPanGestureRecognizer` for dragging `MKMapView` but I'll receive `gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` immediately when the user lift his finger even though the map is scrolling. What I try to figure out is how to prevent loading server data for  my map annotations when the map is still moving and/or the user touches the map one's again to drag the map again? The data load mechanism should be only called when the map stops moving and zooming and is standing still for some predefined time.

This is what I've implement so far:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
...
  UIPanGestureRecognizer* panRec = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didDragMap:)];
  [panRec setDelegate:self];
  [panRec setDelaysTouchesBegan:YES];
  [panRec setDelaysTouchesEnded:YES];
  [panRec setCancelsTouchesInView:YES];
  [self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:panRec];
}
```

And the selector method *didDragMap:*

```
- (void)didDragMap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer {
if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    _searchBar.text = @"";
    _filtered = NO;
    _crosshair.hidden = NO;
    [self removeAllAnnotationExceptOfOriginalLocation];
}
else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    [self performSelector:@selector(delayAddressResolving:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
}
```

}

The selector method *delayAddressResolving:* is loading the needed data from server to display the information for my annotations.

All notes are welcome!

Comment: did you find some Solution for this? I am having the same prob.

Comment: In my case I executed an Independent Thread, which was checking the Lat Long of a Pin I placed in the Middle. if there was change in the current and previous values API will be called. Please share your solution too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following `MKMapViewDelegate` methods:

```
    - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
    - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

These methods are called every time when map region is changing.

Comment: These delegate methods will be called many times to report map position updates as written in the documentation: [Apple-Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:) This won't help to solve the problem to detect the time, when zooming or scrolling of the map view did finished. I need to find out the time when zooming or scrolling did finished to fire my method for downloading server data for my annotations.

Comment: Also, the delegate methods are not called solely in response to user interaction. Animating a layout change that affects the MapView will also result in these methods being called, for example.

Answer (score 0):

[determine if MKMapView was dragged/moved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556977/determine-if-mkmapview-was-dragged-moved)
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Listings/Classes_BreadcrumbViewController_m.html. It may help you

Comment: There is no solution for the described problem in the implementation example you posted, see [Classes_BreadcrumbViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Breadcrumb/Listings/Classes_BreadcrumbViewController_m.html)