# Why my user location is always in center?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

i have a map in my app,i set the center user location when map is open.
I have used this code:

```
 map.delegate=Self; 
 ......
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {

MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;
mapRegion.center = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
mapRegion.span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.5, 0.5); //Zoom distance
[self.mapView setRegion:mapRegion animated: YES];
}
```

But when i move map it came back to user location.
How can i move free into my map without care user location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are resetting the location every time the user's location changes. You should do this only once, e.g.

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {

    if (self.centerToUserLocation)
    {
        MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;
        mapRegion.center = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
        mapRegion.span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.5, 0.5); //Zoom distance
        [self.mapView setRegion:mapRegion animated: YES];
        self.centerToUserLocation = NO;
    }
}
```

Where `centerToUserLocation` is something like `@property (nonatomic) BOOL centerToUserLocation`

Comment: I have used your code but the result the same.when i move map it came back.

Comment: Are you calling -[MKMapView setRegion:animated:] anywhere else?

Comment: No,i have called -[MKMapView setRegion:animated:] just only in didUpdateUserLocation,but i thinks that it call the same when i move out from user location.

Comment: Where are you setting `self.centerToUserLocation` to `YES`?