# Determine if MKMapView was dragged/moved in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, swift2

How do I detect when the user has dragged or move an MKMapView in order to, e.g., prevent automatic homing in on the user's current location.

Answer (score 18):

Note: This answer was made possible and was adapted from Jano's response to the same question for Objective-C here: [determine if MKMapView was dragged/moved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11675587/403406). Thanks [Jano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/412916/jano).

To properly detect a map drag you have to add a UIPanGestureRecognizer. This is the drag gesture recognizer (panning = dragging).

**Step 1:** Add the gesture recognizer in viewDidLoad (Swift 2)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // All your other setup code
    let mapDragRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didDragMap:")
    mapDragRecognizer.delegate = self
    self.mapView.addGestureRecognizer(mapDragRecognizer)
}
```

Swift 3 version of above gesture recognizer setup (selector syntax has changed)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let mapDragRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.didDragMap(gestureRecognizer:)))
    mapDragRecognizer.delegate = self
    self.mapView.addGestureRecognizer(mapDragRecognizer)
}
```

**Step 2:** Add the protocol UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to the view controller so it works as delegate.

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
```

**Step 3:** Add the following code for the UIPanGestureRecognizer to work with the already existing gesture recognizers in MKMapView:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

**Step 4:** In case you want to call your method once instead 50 times per drag, detect either the "drag ended" or "drag began" state in your selector:

```
func didDragMap(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began) {
        print("Map drag began")
    }

    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended) {
        print("Map drag ended")
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone in need!

Comment: What is the difference between this solution and using "regionDidChangeAnimated"?

Comment: how do i go about using step 4 I cant get the func to be called

Comment: @pprevalon - `didDragMap()` is triggered by the mapDragRecognizer's selector. It is probably not being called for you because the syntax for this keeps changing in swift - in swift 3 for example the gesture recognizer would need to be set up like this to trigger the didDragMap function. `let mapPanInteractionRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.didDragMap(gestureRecognizer:)))`.