# Stop Updating Location when I drag the mapview

Tags: swift, swift3, mapkit

I have a mapview which his updating location. So if I am moving my loocating keeps updating.
I want it to stop if I drag the map and try to see another thing on it.
How can I do this?

I tried this solution, to detect when map is dragged:
[Determine if MKMapView was dragged/moved in Swift 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33405449/determine-if-mkmapview-was-dragged-moved-in-swift-2-0)

I am working in swift3.

1: Add the gesture recognizer in viewDidLoad:

```
    let mapDragRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("didDragMap:")))
    mapDragRecognizer.delegate = self
    self.map.addGestureRecognizer(mapDragRecognizer)
```

2: Add the protocol UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to the view controller so it works as delegate.

```
 class MapViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
```

3. Added this other code:

   ```
   func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
   return true
   }

     func didDragMap(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
   if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began) {
       print("Map drag began")
     self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
       }

   if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended) {
       print("Map drag ended")
   }
   }
   ```

The app crashes if I drag map. And I got this:
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[app.ViewController didDragMap:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdf1fd132c0'" (..) "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Comment: It would help if you you show your code that handles the mapview.

Comment: I've updated my question :) Perhaps there is a better solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selector syntax has changed in Swift 3. Your gesture recognizer should now look like this:

```
let mapDragRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didDragMap))

func didDragMap(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
   if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began) {
       print("Map drag began")
       self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
   }
   if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended) {
       print("Map drag ended")
   }
}
```

Note that `didDragMap(_:)` is declared according to the new [Swift API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/)

I would also replace your `if` statements with a `switch` statement as the compiler is able to optimize it better once there are more than two cases, and it is more clear. i.e.

```
func didDragMap(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gestureRecognizer.state {
    case .began:
        print("Map drag began")
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    case .ended:
        print("Map drag ended")

    default:
        break
    }
}
```