# In swift 3 i am currently using Location to do some stuff for my app, i want to check if it gets enabled at some point later in the process

Tags: swift, timer, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I have an application that finds a person coords and uses them for some code, of course if I do not have location enabled I cannot use that, but I want to check if it is enabled later on the site. Example:

User logs in, goes to my tab, has no location so it doesn't show nearest shop, but once he enables location there, a listener tells my code that its on and does stuff accordingly?

I was thinking of using a timer to check every second... but that seems kinda stupid, is there any alternatives? What would be good to implement?

Comment: Have you looked at `CLLocationManager` and `CLLocationManagerDelegate`?

Comment: MKMapView does all that... no need to use "timers". (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11675587/499581)

Answer (score 0):

In your screen where you have required location, just check whether location service is enabled or not.

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.checkLocationServiceEnabled()
}

func checkLocationServiceEnabled()
{
    let locationAuthorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

    switch locationAuthorizationStatus {

    case .AuthorizedAlways ,.AuthorizedWhenInUse ,.NotDetermined ,.Restricted:
        break
    case .Denied:
        self.alertTurnOnLocationFromDevicePrivacySetting()
    }
}

func alertTurnOnLocationFromDevicePrivacySetting()
{
    let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                                  Int64(1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(
                title: ALERT_TURN_ON_LOCATION_FROM_DEVICE_PRIVACY,
                message: "",
                preferredStyle: .Alert)

            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: ALERT_OK, style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

            self.navigationController?.topViewController!.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```