# fix a MKPointAnnotation to centre of map (MapKit) even while user is scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapview, mapkitannotation

I need to fix an MKPointAnnotation to the center of the map even while the user is scrolling the map, it should still stay in middle. just like Ola app
By far I achieved searching, setting annotation to the center of the map and changing annotation to center again when user scrolls
however it updates when the user stops scrolling, but I want it to stay in the middle always so the user can scroll to an exact location.

Comment: just put an image of a map pin in the centre of the view. Over the top of the view. it wouldn't then move with the map scrolling

Comment: Thank you for replying, I tried using the button but I was thinking if it can be done using annotation itself

Comment: it can yes but you need to constantly update its position as you scroll

Comment: Could you help me with that? updating location constantly

Comment: See this other answer, tells you how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556977/determine-if-mkmapview-was-dragged-moved

Comment: I used Uibutton with same pin image and used bounce animation which looks like exactly what i wanted , thanks for your help